# Difference between php5_module vs mod_php5

Tags: php5, apache2

I am using remi's php repositories to use php5.6 in parallel with php 7, and so my apache config file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php56-php.conf` is like so:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp56-php5.so
</IfModule>
```

However my main php config (`/etc/httpd/conf.d/php56-php.conf`) looks for the apache module as follows:

```
...
<IfModule  mod_php5.c>
...
```

So which is it? Do I have to change that IFModule to `php5_module`? How do I know my loaded module `php5_module` corresponds to `mod_php5.c`?

Answer (score 1):

libphp56-php5.so is the file name, mod_php5 is the module name, provided by the previous file.

Notice: you cannot use multiple versions with mod_php.

I recommend you to read: [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but is there a way to know which file provides what module?

Comment: The file name is the one given on the LoadModule directive.